# Creating Folder on External Storage

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

I am trying to create folder on external microsd card but it is not working.

```
String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sdcard/Ankur Jain";

Toast.makeText(Second.this,sdpath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

File file = new File(sdpath);
if(!file.exists()){file.mkdirs();
    Toast.makeText(Second.this,"Created path",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

i have added all permission too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and build gradle app as below

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jss.intentgame"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Now what is stopping to create folder on card?

Comment: Can you tell me in which version are you trying to execute it?

Comment: Actually, I hope you know well about the permission feature in android.

Comment: Another point as @commonsWare mentioned that there is no code related to create the directory. Please check how to create folder in Java.

Comment: i am testing on kitkat and above. did i mentioned wrong permissions or missed some?

Answer (score 0):

First, `new File()` does not create a file. It creates a `File` object. Your question has no code for creating a file or directory.

Second, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sdcard/Ankur Jain"` will not point to "external microsd card" on most, if not all, Android devices. That points to some subdirectory that you are trying to create on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Third, you do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

If you want to allow the user to work with removable storage, use [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) on Android 4.4+. There was no Android SDK support for removable storage prior to that.

Comment: i missed to paste directory create code. i hope it is bit sensible now. can u guide further.

Comment: it i making directory now but in internal  storage..how to get path of microsd?

Comment: @AnkurJain: "it i making directory now but in internal storage" -- the code in your question is working with what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "how to get path of microsd?" -- you do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share the basic working code that you can see and try accordingly. Hope this would help you to create the folder.

1. For creating the Folder on SD card, First define the Path and Directory Name. After that, I created one class that hold methods that return location, absolute Path reference.

```
public class AppConst{
    private static String APPLICATION_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    private static String DIR_HOME = “YourRootDirName”;
        private static String IMAGE_HOME = “SubDirectoryName”;

        private static String getApplicationPath() {
         return (APPLICATION_PATH + "/");
        }

       public static String getRootPath() {
        return (getApplicationPath() + DIR_HOME + "/");
       }
        public static String getImageAbsolutePath() {
        return getRootPath() + IMAGE_HOME + "/";
       }
}
```

2. After creating the Constants class, Next We create the StorageManager that would help us to create the directory. This class requires the help from AppConst to get and know the absolute location of the direction location.

```
public class StorageManager {
    public static void verifyImagePath() {
        File imageDirectory = new File(AppConst.getImageAbsolutePath());// It use the path that we define in constant file.
        if (!imageDirectory.exists()) {
            imageDirectory.mkdir();
        }
    }
}
}
```

3. Now In your application, Find out the place where you want to start creating the folder and write this below code.

   ```
   StorageManager. verifyImagePath();
   ```
4. The above statement does create the folder on defined location on Storage option.

> Note: Make sure you must give the read/write permission
>   in your app Manifest file. If you are running the app in marshmallow
>   device make sure you award the read/write permission to your
>   application.

Comment: No change. still getting same result, folders are created in internal storage only. private static String APPLICATION_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    private static String DIR_HOME = "sdcard1";
    private static String IMAGE_HOME = "Ankur Jain"; either i use sdcard, the folder is created in Internal memory

Answer (score 0):

I got the trick to solve my issues. Get list of storage devices, trim its path and we will get absolute path for sdcard storage. With normal mkdris create folder. Here is code.

```
 File[] externalStorageFiles = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MainActivity.this, null);
    storagepath = new String[externalStorageFiles.length];                                              for (int i = 0; i < externalStorageFiles.length; i++) {
      storagepath[i] = externalStorageFiles[i].toString();
            System.out.println(storagepath[i]);
                                              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to getPath() instead of getAbsolutePath(). Working in my case for all the conditions.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```